# Angular 8 Jasmine/Karma spyOn behavior questions

Tags: angularjs, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a directive with custom **debounce** decorators. The directive is a fairly simple that listen on "scroll" event.

```
export class MyScrollDirective {
    @Output() scrolled = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
    //debouce is added to prevent multiple call when scroll reach the end
    //in the if statement below
    @myDebounce(300)
    onScroll(event) {
      this.scrolled.emit(null);
    }
}
```

In my test, I have an assumption that `this.scrolled.emit()` will be called whenever  `onScroll` is called. Obviously this is not the case.

With the debounce, it looks like `onScroll` can be called multiple times from `spyOn` while `this.scrolled` only emit once. For example, if I trigger scroll events 2 times in my test within 300ms intervals, the `onScroll` is called 2 time while the `this.scrolled` has only 1 **emit**. The 1 emit is of course desired behavior, but how come `onScroll` is called twice. When the app is actually running in browser - instead of tests - the `onScroll` is actually called only once.

Why is this?!

The test detail can be view at [StackBliz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-qupkke?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question!

In order to get a better understanding of how things work, I'd recommend opening this [forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-rws8u4?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts) and place these breakpoints:

- `jasmine.js`

  - `calls.push(context);` - line 2162
  - `{` - line 5972
- `myDebounceDecorator.ts`

  - `descriptor.value` - line 16
  - `var params = [];` - line 18
- `dummy.component.spec.ts`

  - `vsCss.triggerEventHandler(...)` - line 36
  - `vsCss.triggerEventHandler(...)` - line 40

*Note: I've used Firefox Dev Tools*

This is what happens after you refresh the app:

- `descriptor.value;` is reached; this means that the **spy** will be applied on the newly created function:

```js
descriptor.value = function () { /* this will be spied */ }
```

- `vsCss.triggerEventHandle` (line 36) is reached
- `var callData = {` is reached, because of the spy.
- `calls.push(context);` is reached, which means the spy(`onScroll`) was called
- `var params = [];` is reached, because the spy was defined with `callThrough()`, which means that the original implementation will be used
- `vsCss.triggerEventHandler` (line 40) is reached
- `var callData = {` is reached, because of the spy
- `calls.push(context);` is reached again; if we were to hover over `calls`, we'd see that it already has an element(from the previous `vsCss.triggerEventHandle`), hence the `calls`' length will be 2
- `var params = [];` - the original implementation is used
- `var callData = {` is reached; this time, it's the spy what we used on the `Subject`(i.e `EventEmitter`); we can be sure of this by hovering over `this` from `object: this`
- `calls.push(context);` - `calls` belongs to the Subject's spied method
- `var callData = {` is reached; this time, the spy belongs to `onDummy` method
- `calls.push(context);` - `onDummy`'s spy

Comment: Andrei, thanks. This is very helpful. It looks like it is Jasmine's implementation - it depends on ```var callData``` array items count to count how many times a function is called, correct? In short summary, the app's ```onScroll``` is only called once when it is running in browser but Jasmine records it 2 times during the test due to Jasmine's implementation. The way Jasmine interprets the behavior is just confusing  when you expect ```onScroll``` and ```EventEmitter``` will have same # of calls.

Comment: @yial2 I don't think it's Jasmine's fault at all, the thing is that the spy is applied on the **decorated** function, **not** the original one(`originalMethod` in your decorator). The original function is called only once, but the **new** impl of `onScroll` is called every time the scroll event happens.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. This is very helpful!

Comment: It was my pleasure to help! Good luck